# Akka ask onComplete called twice

Tags: java, akka, future

I've got an actor asking another actor something with a timeout.

Sometimes the onComplete handlers onReceive gets called twice. The last call is an AskTimeout, the first call I haven't had a chance to debug or log yet.

I cannot find any docs saying explicitly that onComplete should only be called once. Are multiple calls to be expected or a bug?

I use Java 1.6, Akka 2.1.1 and Scala library 2.10.0

Comment: The question itself is I think good, but please add small sections of code (preferably an SSCCE) to be totally fit for the site, and for those involved to be able to help.

Comment: Sorry, but its kinda hard to produce a SSCCE when I don't know how to reproduce the issue. I could of course create two actors and do an ask with a completehandler, but that would not examplify what I'm asking.

This issue happens something like every 48 hours in our live system. I suspect it has something to do with the actor being asked replying at the same time the timeout kicks in.